# Django - Cannot find Directory 'mysite'

Tags: python, django, windows-7-x64

I am currently learning how to use Python/Django. I have successfully installed and setup Django. I am experiencing problems creating a project using the `django-admin startproject mysite` command. I have executed the command from command prompt using the path: `C:\Python34\Scripts\django-admin startproject mysite` I tried searching for it in the current directory but could not find the folder. I tried executing the command again and found out that the directory exists in:

`'C:\Windows\system32\mysite'`

I tried searching for it in this directory, but could not find it. How can I make this directory visible and set it under the Python directory?

Here is the exact error I am getting in Command Prompt:

`CommandError: 'C:\Windows\system32\mysite' already exists`

I am currently running Windows 7 - 64 Bit

Comment: Why are you doing any of this under `system32` at all?

Comment: This is because you're in that directory `c:\Windows\system32`. You need to change directory using `cd <what path you want>`. Then followed by that `django-admin startproject mysite` command

Comment: For example: `cd c:\\ ` to change directory to your root directory. then type `C:\Python34\Scripts\django-admin startproject mysite`. It will then create the directory under `C:\mysite`

Comment: @mevius I didn't do nothing at all. It set itself to this location

Comment: @n0t_a_nUmb3R because by default when you open command prompt is in that `system32` directory. you need to change it first

Comment: I guess you can now answer your own question :) Good luck learning

Comment: @n0t_a_nUmb3R just to help you about the `django-admin` command, it is good if you add `C:\Python34\Scripts` in your system environment path.

Comment: Ah! That worked out fine. Why don't you post an answer. I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To Summarize the comments:

This is because you're in `c:\Windows\system32`. By default when you open command prompt is in that `system32` directory. you need to change it first. To change directory use `cd <what path you want>`.

Once you're in the correct directory, you can start the project with `django-admin startproject` command.

For example: `cd c:\` to change directory to your root directory. then type `C:\Python34\Scripts\django-admin startproject mysite`. It will then create the directory under `C:\mysite`

Last but not least, you can also put `C:\Python34\Scripts` in your system environment variable `PATH`, so that you don't have to type the full address of `django-admin`. Instead you can then use the `django-admin startproject mysite`.

Comment: Thanks. Just launched my first Python App in the web browser